# question about Riemann zeta $\zeta (0)$

Tags: calculus, riemann-zeta

i know that

$$\zeta (m)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-m}$$

so

$$\zeta (0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^0=1+1+1+1+1+1+\cdots=\infty $$

but actually

$$\zeta (0)=-0.5$$

where is the wrong

**please help**

**thanks for all**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also struggled with this for a while. Your definition of the Riemann zeta function is only its definition when the real part of $ m $ is greater than $ 1 $.

The domain of $ \zeta $ though is $ \mathbb{C} $, so the question is: how do we move from $ \{z \mid \Re(z) > 1 \} $ to $ \mathbb{C} $? The answer is [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Using the functional equation for $ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z} $, we can extend the domain of $ \zeta $ to the complex numbers.

If you want to know the details, I suggest looking at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) on the function.

Comment: The domain of $\zeta$ excludes $1$, beware (there is a pole there).